# Am I using correctly scalene profiler for python code?

Tags: python, profiler, scalene

I'm trying to use Scalene to profile some python code.
When I run:

```
scalene --reduced-profile --html --outfile ./profiling/profile_name_file.html ./profiling/profiling_script.py
```

I get two error messages:

> [1205/174847.087563:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not
> found [1205/174847.110144:ERROR:directory_reader_posix.cc(42)] opendir
> /home/user/.config/google-chrome/Crash
> Reports/attachments/82a5951a-f981-4d23-badc-a9487b65f7c0: No such file
> or directory (2)

Afterwards, I go to the directory from which I ran the bash command, and I find a `profile.html`, instead of a `profile_name_file.html` inside the `profiling` folder.

When I open that html file, the graphs look very odd.
[image]

Comment: Agree, I couldn't really make heads or tails out of what it was saying.  Too pretty, too graphic-focussed, not enough meat.  For one thing, I'd like to see an actual YouTube of Scalene being *used* to profile something.  Not a 30 minute lecture about Scalene's advantages and comparison to other profilers.  Passing for now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are using the correct profiler. As documented [here](https://github.com/plasma-umass/scalene) the timeline is visualized as [sparklines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparkline), which are small line charts. You might consider looking at CLI output (see below) or scaling the workload of profiling_script.py as Scalene can only profile code that runs for at least one second or allocates at least 10MB.

[image: CLI output]